# Start cronjob at specific epoch time in golang

Tags: go, cron, epoch

I am using [github.com/robfig/cron](https://github.com/robfig/cron) library. I want to run cronjob at epoc time with millisecond and work every second. The cron starts at `000` millisecond. I need it to start at specific times.

For example if I take the following:

```
c := cron.New()
c.AddFunc("@every 1s", func() { 
      // Do Something 
   })
c.Start()
```

And run it at `1657713890300` epoc timestamp then I want the function to run at:

- `1657713891300`
- `1657713892300`
- `1657713893300`.

Currently, cron running at

- `1657713891000`
- `1657713892000`
- `1657713893000`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `@every 1s` the [library creates](https://github.com/robfig/cron/blob/v3.0.1/parser.go#L430) a [`ConstantDelaySchedule`](https://github.com/robfig/cron/blob/v3/constantdelay.go#L24) which "rounds so that the next activation time will be on the second".

If that is not what you want then you can create your own scheduler ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/vgiJYgDcGUf)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/robfig/cron/v3"
)

func main() {
    time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond) // So we don't start cron too near the second boundary
    c := cron.New()

    c.Schedule(CustomConstantDelaySchedule{time.Second}, cron.FuncJob(func() {
        fmt.Println(time.Now().UnixNano())
    }))
    c.Start()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
}

// CustomConstantDelaySchedule is a copy of the libraries ConstantDelaySchedule with the rounding removed
type CustomConstantDelaySchedule struct {
    Delay time.Duration
}

// Next returns the next time this should be run.
func (schedule CustomConstantDelaySchedule) Next(t time.Time) time.Time {
    return t.Add(schedule.Delay)
}
```

Follow up: The above uses the `time.Time` passed to `Next` which is [`time.Now()`](https://github.com/robfig/cron/blob/v3/cron.go#L270) so will the time will slowly advance over time.

Addressing this is possible (see below - [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/yGHi5yGQ-uy)) but doing this introduces some potential issuers (the `CustomConstantDelaySchedule` must not be reused and if the jobs take too long to run then you will still end up with discrepancies). I'd suggest that you consider moving away from the cron package and just use a [`time.Ticker`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Ticker).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/robfig/cron/v3"
)

func main() {
    time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond) // So we don't start cron too nead the second boundary
    c := cron.New()

    c.Schedule(CustomConstantDelaySchedule{Delay: time.Second}, cron.FuncJob(func() {
        fmt.Println(time.Now().UnixNano())
    }))
    c.Start()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
}

// CustomConstantDelaySchedule is a copy of the libraries ConstantDelaySchedule with the rounding removed
// Note that because this stored the last time it cannot be reused!
type CustomConstantDelaySchedule struct {
    Delay      time.Duration
    lastTarget time.Time
}

// Next returns the next time this should be run.
func (schedule CustomConstantDelaySchedule) Next(t time.Time) time.Time {
    if schedule.lastTarget.IsZero() {
        schedule.lastTarget = t.Add(schedule.Delay)
    } else {
        schedule.lastTarget = schedule.lastTarget.Add(schedule.Delay)
    }
    return schedule.lastTarget
}
```

Comment: Thank you, bro. It is working. The runtime is increasing by 1-2 milliseconds every time the scheduler runs. An occasional 1-2 millisecond overshoot would not affect the process. But the constant increase disrupts the process. Help, please!

Comment: I'm not sure that `cron` is the right tool for this job... I've provided a method but you are getting outside of the scope of cron.

Comment: Before, I did it in Node.js using node-cron. But now I have to move it to golang. Can you ask me advice for it? How can I fix it?

Comment: If you just want to schedule a function to run every X milliseconds then [time.Tick](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Tick) is a simple solution (see the example in the docs, it does exactly what you are asking for and is much simpler that pulling in a Cron library).